# Sanitize $data & $item function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to make sanitize `function` to keep rest of the code simple.
Since I'm using `MYSQLi` I wonder if the following code is correct?

```
function sanitize ($data){
    global $db_connect;
    return htmlentities(strip_tags($db_connect->real_escape_string($data)));
}

function array_sanitize ($item) {
    global $db_connect;
    $item = htmlentities(strip_tags($db_connect->real_escape_string($item)));
}
```

Comment: Do you also want to sanitize arrays? Both methods look the same to me?(but valid). Also keep in mind prepared statements will eliminate the need for sanitation.

Comment: `htmlentities()` is only intended for data to be displayed on a web page, not database queries. It's unlikely the database has data encoded like `&amp;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two reasons why you sanitize the string:

**Prevent from SQL injections**

You should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using `real_escape_string()` to prevent from SQL injections. The Mysqli Extension supports prepared statements. They are most secure and easy to use. Use them.

**Prevent from XSS attacks**

To prevent from XSS attacks `htmlentities()` and `strip_tags()` may help. You should also make sure, that the functions handling the input charset correctly.

You should also read this document from [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet)